# How to deal with different environment on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have an app on the App Store and I'm still writing features on it so most of the time I need to have the production version on my phone and the dev. version as well.

I managed to do it by changing manually the bundle id but it is a bit exhausting to do that each time.

Is there any framework, SDK or best practice available to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another target. Make sure all your files in the original are in the second, except for the plist file with the bundle ID. Remember to always add new files to both targets. Now you can build one target, or the other, easily by selecting that target to build.

I did exactly this to build a iPhone, iPad, and Universal app and for a while needed the first two until the second was working properly.